# php insert mysql with while loop

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get datas from a mySQL table and want to insert every row (that my query get) into another table.

With following code i get my Datas:

```
$cart = new Dbconn();
$query = new Dbconn();
if ($cart->pdo()) {
   $cart->stmt("SELECT id, product FROM cart WHERE uid =:uid");
   $cart->bindParam(':uid', Session::get('uid'));
   $cart->exe();
}
```

After i get the data i want to insert it, with a while loop

```
while ($rowPay = $cart->fetch()) {
    if ($query->pdo()) {
       $query->stmt('INSERT INTO orders (products_id, order_id) VALUES(:uid, :products)');
       $query->bindParam(':user_id', Session::get('uid'));
       $query->bindParam(':products', $rowPay['product']);
       $query->exe();
    }
}
```

He get all Datas but insert only the first entry. Where is my mistake?

Greetings

Comment: is your selection outside the loop?

Comment: @devpro he is using fetch, not fetchall though apparently someone says he does not need a fetchall doing it this way, personally I would set a fetch all then use a foreach to loop through all the results.

Comment: Where do you get `$payCart` variable from.

Comment: $payCart was my old variable. (edited at top)

Comment: fixed. There was an error in on of my variables. After restarting my mac it works.. -_- sry guys

Answer (score 0):

If it insert only the first entry, then there is a problem with the parameters you try to insert.
You probably try to insert several rows with the same primary key.
I need to know where is the primary key in each table in order to help you more.

Comment: my only primary key is a auto inc, which i don't insert with my query

Answer (score 0):

$payCart->fetch() fetches single row and $payCart->fetchAll() fetches all rows.

Try as this

```
while ($rowPay = $payCart->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       if ($query->pdo()) {
           $query->stmt('INSERT INTO orders'
                       .'(products_id, order_id)'
                       .'VALUES(:uid, :products)');
           $query->bindParam(':user_id', Session::get('uid'));
           $query->bindParam(':products', $rowPay['product']);
           $query->exe();}}
```